# Trouble calling SystemParametersInfo

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, pinvoke

Recently I've been trying to call the `SystemParametersInfo` method from managed code, without any success.

The problem is that, after calling the method, the method returns `false` (indicating failure), however `GetLastError` (retrieved by  `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`) is `0`.

I tried to invoke the method from C++ as a test (with the exact same parameters), and it works completely fine from there.

The P/Invoke declaration of the method is this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(SPI uiAction, int uiParam, ref STICKYKEYS pvParam, SPIF fWinIni);

internal struct STICKYKEYS 
{
  public int cbSize;
  public int dwFlags;
}
```

And the invocation is as follows:

```
NativeMethods.STICKYKEYS stickyKeys = default(NativeMethods.STICKYKEYS);
bool result = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(NativeMethods.SPI.SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS, StickyKeysSize, ref stickyKeys, 0);
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

The `SPI.SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS` is`0x003A` (as seen on MSDN).

Here the result is `false`, and the error returned is `0`.
Also this is complied as a 64-bit executable if that matters.

I'm completely at my wit's end, do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: not really an answer, but did you take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says, *Set the `cbSize` member of this structure and the `uiParam` parameter to `sizeof(STICKYKEYS)`.* Are you doing this?

Comment: @Benj It would appear sticky keys are not there.

Comment: @GSerg I'm trying to read the value first (that's why the function is called with SPI_GETSTICKYKEY). Afaict, in this case, pvParam should function as an output parameter. (Basically I'm trying to reimplement this snippet in C#:[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Comment: @GSerg Ah, sorry, I' didn't read your answer thoroughly enough. Will try to set the cbSize parameter, and I'll report back with the results.

Comment: @GSerg Yup! I've set the cbSize parameter, and it seems to be working fine. In my defense, I already passed the size of the struct to the function, so I didn't expect that I'd need to pass it twice :). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As GSerg pointed it out to me, my issue was that I need to pass in the size of the struct both directly as a parameter, and as the `cbSize` member of the struct that I passed in by reference.
The correct code is:

```
        int stickyKeysSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (NativeMethods.STICKYKEYS));
        NativeMethods.STICKYKEYS stickyKeys = new NativeMethods.STICKYKEYS {cbSize = stickyKeysSize, dwFlags = 0};
        bool result = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo(NativeMethods.SPI.SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS, stickyKeysSize, ref stickyKeys, 0);
        if (!result) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        return stickyKeys;
```